# C++ sort intervals struct as well as removing overlapping intervals

Tags: c++, sorting, set

Here intervals is the same as Line. Although I figured out the correct solution for the two purposes:

1) sort intervals;

2) reject when adding intervals overlapping with existing ones.

```
struct Line {
    int down;
    int up;

    Line(int down, int up) {
        this->down = down;
        this->up = up;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto cmp = [] (const Line& a, const Line& b) {//NOTE: this can even detect the intersection, as well as sort the interval!!
        if (a.up <= b.down) return true;
        else return false;
    };

    set<Line, decltype(cmp)> s(cmp);
    Line l1{2, 3};
    Line l2{3, 5};
    Line l3{1, 2}; //success for insertion
    Line l4{4, 6}; //fail for insertion b/c of insersection


    auto ret = s.insert(l2);
    cout << "insert 3->5 ";
    if (ret.second) cout << "success " << endl;
    else cout << "fail " << endl;

    ret = s.insert(l3);
    cout << "insert 1->2 ";
    if (ret.second) cout << "success " << endl;
    else cout << "fail " << endl;

    ret = s.insert(l1);
    cout << "insert 2->3 ";
    if (ret.second) cout << "success " << endl;
    else cout << "fail " << endl;

    ret = s.insert(l4);
    cout << "insert 4->6 ";
    if (ret.second) cout << "success " << endl;
    else cout << "fail " << endl;

    return 0;
}

Output:
insert 3->5 success
insert 1->2 success
insert 2->3 success
insert 4->6 fail
set finally contains: 1->2, 2->3, 3->5,
```

There is something still puzzling to me:

1) Why is simply comparing `a.up <= b.down` enough to detect overlapping intervals?

Shouldn't we do something like standard approach of detecting interval overlapping?

```
max(a.down, b.down) < min(a.up, b.up)
```

2) The 3rd step is not clear to me

```
insert 3->5 success
insert 1->2 success //OK, b/c 2 <= 3, a.up <= b.down return true
insert 2->3 success //Why success? 3 > 1, i.e., a.up > b.down, return false; does it only compare with interval 3->5?
```

3) Why does below code not work for removing overlapping intervals?

```
    auto cmp_set = [](const Line& a, const Line& b) {
        if (max(a.down, b.down) < min(a.up, b.up)) return 0; //standard way to detect overlapping of intervals
        else { //sort the two intervals 
            if(a.up <= b.down) return -1;
            else return 1;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Why is simply comparing a.up <= b.down enough to detect overlapping intervals?

`[a.down, a.up[` overlaps `[b.down, b.up[` when `max(a.down, b.down) < min(a.up, b.up)`
which is equivalent to `a.down < b.up && b.down < a.up` (remember that we also have `a.down <= a.up && b.down <= b.up` from interval definition).

We can also list possibilities:

- `a.down < a.up < b.down < b.up` `(a < b)`
- `a.down < b.down < a.up < b.up` Intersection
- `a.down < b.down < b.up < a.up` Intersection (Totally included)
- `b.down < a.down < a.up < b.up` Intersection (Totally included)
- `b.down < a.down < b.up < a.up` Intersection
- `b.down < b.up < a.down < a.up` `(b < a)`

> The 3rd step is not clear to me
>
> `insert 3->5 success
>   insert 1->2 success //OK, b/c 2 <= 3, a.up <= b.down return true
>   insert 2->3 success //Why success? 3 > 1, i.e., a.up > b.down, return false; does it only compare with interval 3->5?`

```
Line l1{2, 3};
Line l2{3, 5};
Line l3{1, 2};
Line l4{4, 6};
```

To insert `l1` in `{l3, l2}`

- `l1 < l2` so `l1` is before `l2`
- `!(l1 < l3)` so `l1` is not before `l3`
- `l3 < l1` so `l1` is after `l3`
  -> `{l3, l1, l2}`

For `l4` in `{l3, l1, l2}` We have:

- `!(l4 < l2)` (similarly for `l3` and `l1`) so `l4` is not before `l2`
- `!(l2 < l4)`  so `l4` is not after `l2`

we have both `!(l2 < l4) && !(l4 < l2)` so there are *equivalent*, we don't insert `l4`.

> 3) Why does below code not work for removing overlapping intervals?

I don't understand where you use it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Question 3), I am using the lambda function in set<Line, decltype(cmp)> s(cmp), i.e., replace the a.up <= b.down comparison with lambda function in Question 3); To summarize, for Question 1) the 6 cases listed show that just comparing a.up <= b.down it enough to cover the only 2 valid cases of non-overlapping!  Smart! 2) the set insert fails when there are equivalent elements, thus, only !(l1 < l3) is not enought to reject l1, thus l1 is accepted.

Comment: comparer should sastify `bool operator<` semantic. Your returns -1, 0, 1. So true, false, true. Which is not what you want anyway.

Comment: I see. So -1 also means true, right? b/c it is != 0

Comment: Yes, any non-zero number is `true`.